Sending real-time upload progress over websocket FastAPI
I am building a backend with FastAPI in which i am planning to recieve large files from client on the server and then send it to discord.
I want something like when user is uploading the data i want to show a real-time progress to but i am having hard time doing it so i want to achive something like
When user uploads the file it updates user after each chunk is sent to discord but not real-time
This progress could be any.

from server to discord
while True:
try:
chunk = await file.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
if not chunk:
break
chunk_id += 1
total_size += len(chunk)
message_id = await bot.upload_chunk(chunk, file.filename, chunk_id)
try:
await manager.send_message(f"Uploaded {total_size} bytes")
except Exception as e:
# logging.error(f"Failed to send WebSocket message: {e}")
print(f"Failed to send WebSocket message: {e}")
            chunk_entry = FileChunk(
                file_name=file.filename,
                chunk_id=chunk_id,
                discord_message_id=message_id,
                folder_id=folder_id
            )
            db.add(chunk_entry)
            uploaded_chunks.append(chunk_entry)
        except Exception as e:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error uploading chunk {chunk_id}: {str(e)}")

    await db.commit()
try:
    await manager.send_message("Upload complete")
except Exception as e:
    # logging.error(f"Failed to send WebSocket completion message: {e}")
    print(f"Failed to send WebSocket completion message: {e}")
return {
    "message": "File uploaded successfully",
    "filename": file.filename,
    "chunks": chunk_id
}



Here is the code snippet that could help you.
I tried a method in which it divides this 24mb chunk into subchunks and then shows the progress, but then i realized that will start uploading that sub chunks.

On a side note, you might find this answer and this answer helpful, with regard to uploading large files in FastAPI

A progress bar for the upload to the server would normally be handled on the client side in JavaScript. The various JavaScript http apis have mechanisms for that. Providing user feedback on something your middleware is doing (here, the upload to discord) could be handled by some kind of push notification or by an api for the client to query job status. This answer might help.
